# I want to scrape this 400 from a class as shown in the picture, but it's returning none. Any solutions?

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is the screenshot of the class i want to get text from.[Class picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8b1v.png)

My code

```
     r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.ae/sbbn=12303875031&rh=n%3A12303875031%2Cp_n_prime_domestic%3A20642115031&dc&qid=1616415023&rnid=20642114031&ref=lp_12303875031_nr_p_n_prime_domestic_0", headers=headers)
     soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
     b=soup.find("li",{"class":"a-disabled"})
     print(b)
```

Output:
[code ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moWv5.png)

Website link: https://www.amazon.ae/s?i=fashion&bbn=11995844031&rh=n%3A11995844031%2Cp_n_prime_domestic%3A20642115031&dc&page=11&qid=1616522805&rnid=20642114031&ref=sr_pg_11

Comment: The link in your code yields a 404 error. Make sure the URL works in your browser, then make it a habit of checking the HTTP status code after issuing a request. It should usually be 200, unless you are working with APIs.

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you actually have the contents of the page i.e. `print r.text or r.content` to confirm you have the page contents.

Not sure what version of beautifulsoup you are using but you can also try the syntax

`company_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='company')`

Refer to this [documentation](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/#find-elements-by-html-class-name)